When running a Pyinstaller .exe error occurs
The error message is:
File "SAE v.0.0.1.py", line 8, in 
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
And here's the code:
print("[My name] SAE Project v.0.0.1.")
print("1. FFA History.")
print("2. AG History.")
print("3. FFA Meaning.")
print("4. AG Meaning.")
print("5. Why Is FFA important?")
print("6. Why is AG Important?")
choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
if choice == 1:
    print("The National FFA Organization (formerly known as the Future Farmers of America) was founded in 1928. It began as an organization for boys interested in farming but has since evolved into an inclusive student organization promoting agricultural education. The FFA aims to develop students' leadership, personal growth, and career success through agricultural education.")
if choice == 2:
    print("Not yet implemented.")
if choice == 3:
    print("Not yet implemented.")
if choice == 4:
    print("Not yet implemented.")
if choice == 5:
    print("Not yet implemented.")
if choice == 6:
    print("Not yet implemented.")

I tried to run an .exe I compiled with Pyinstaller, and it spits out an error message.
